# Why does my kitchen faucet stop and start at full pressure only for a split second, both cold and hot?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, faucet

My kitchen faucet stops and starts at full pressure only for a split second, both cold and hot. This has been going on for about a month. I moved some plumbing over 4 feet in the basement 3 months back, with no issue at my sink until a month ago.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This symptom is common with external sprayers. The diverter causes water to shutoff from the faucet when the sprayer is in use. The external sprayer may be leaking (into the sink, or under it) or the diverter valve itself may be failing. If you have a sprayer, check both ends of the hose for leaks and fix that if you find any. If not, remove the valve and make sure there's nothing that can be easily cleaned or a bad washer that can be replaced. As a last resort, take the valve to the store to find an exact replacement.

Answer (score 0):

...or, you have something (side effect of moving your plumbing) that took a couple of months to jam up your pipes. But the fact that it's happening on both, not just hot or just cold, suggests that @BMitch is probably on the right track. Having had a "hot side only issue" that traced to a nearly plugged elbow, I feel a need to keep the idea out there when symptoms suggest a similarity.

A related possibility is that something has traveled along the pipes and actually jammed in the faucet itself. If you get full force flow from the faucet feed lines (if you disconnect them and run them into a bucket), the problem is somewhere in the faucet or diverter.